# 2 articles with same "data-type"

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a select menu with various options and images below that change accordingly to what we choose in the options.
I managed to get help from stackoverflow using this code.

```
 $(".filter").change(function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    var row = $('.categorias'); 

    row.hide()
    row.each(function(i, el) {
         if($(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue) {
             $(el).show();

         }
    })
    // In Addition to Wlin's Answer (For "All" value)
  if ("all" == filterValue) {
    row.show();
  }


});
```

This works just fine this way. With only one "data-type".

```
<article class="portfolio-item categorias" data-type="desporto">
```

But the problem is that some articles have 2, 3 or even 4 types and if i add another data type he only assumes the first one. How can i make one article have the data-types i want?

Comment: it's like the class attribute: data-type="datatype1 datatype2 datatype3" and so on

Comment: I already tried that.

<article class="portfolio-item" data-type="desporto publico">

When i do this the article just won't show up when i select the category. It only works if i put one data-type ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    row.each(function(i, el) {
         if($(el).attr('data-type').split(' ').indexOf(filterValue) !== -1) {
             $(el).show();

         }
    })
```

or

```
row.each(function(i, el) {
     if($(el).data('type').split(' ').indexOf(filterValue) !== -1) {
         $(el).show();

     }
})
```

Comment: that worked as i sad thanks :).
Now imagine i have 20 photos ( the articles) and only  3 of them are in "sports" category. when i choose sports the correct articles appear but the other's just stay hidden. if i have the 3 first articles in that category i will be left with a long dark page with all of the others hidden. 
Is there someway i could fix that?
Im beginner in javascript sorry for dumb questions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what data structure you're using but, as far as I can imagine, you could put data-type as a list of types separated by commas (for example: `data-type="type1,type2,type3"`) and your JavaScript code, taking advantage to make some better, could look like this:

```
$(".filter").change(function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    var row = $('.categorias'); 

    if ("all" == filterValue) {
        row.show();
    } else {
        row.each(function(i, el) {
            if ($(el).attr('data-type').contains(filterValue)) {
                $(el).show();
            } else {
                row.hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```